# Getting data out of my app code and into my rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, automated-tests

I'm not sure how exactly to approach this kind of test in rspec, or if it is even possible.

My specific scenario is about email confirmation:

1) The `user#save` method uses `SecureRandom` to generate a string of bytes (the email confirmation code), Bcrypts it, and stores the result in the database. The original random code (unhashed) is also emailed to the user.

2) My `user#confirm_email` method takes in the email confirmation code and uses BCrypt to hash it and compare it against the existing hash in the database.'

Everything works fine but I'm unclear how to test the scenario, given that the input to `#confirm_email` is random, created within `#save`, and not stored anywhere that my test can access.

Is there a clean way for my code to pass information to my test, outside of method return values? I've considered storing the code in a temp file and then reading the file from the test, but I'm curious if there is a better way.

Comment: Please give more information about type of test. Is it acceptance test, and required to be "black box", or a lower-level unit test? No reason why a *unit test* could not either be given access to the saved code, or have suitable mocks applied. A little bit of test code, and/or the code for the methods you want to test might help when explaining this.

Comment: @NeilSlater - Good point -- The test doesn't have to be black box. How could I use mocks here? I've tried but never really understood how to use them successfully before. Most of my tests just exercise the code and then check the output or consequence in the database. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocking replaces a method in your code with something from your test. Which is exactly what you are asking to do.

Using the [rspec mocking framework](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) as an example, you could, in your test, write:

```
allow(SecureRandom).to receive(:random_bytes).and_return("My Test String")
```

Then use the same input string to your `#confirm_email` code. Presuming you are not doing an integration test.

For testing just the `#confirm_email` method, you could create the record in the database first using a known string of bytes to create the encrypted data.